# How to set font to default from within a predefined environment?

Tags: fonts, moderncv, slanted, default

`moderncv`'s `\cventry` environment defines for its 3rd argument a slanted font:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

I'd like to keep that slanted font, but have a way to interject it with the default font, so that I could write something like

```
\cventry{year}{project}{SLANTED_company1 {\sfdefault AND} SLANTED_company2}{city}{country}{description}
```

so the output would be "*SLANTED_company1* AND *SLANTED_company2*".

How could I do this?

Comment: `\textup{\textsf{and}}` ?

Comment: Thank you, perfect! If you put that as an answer, I'll happily accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\textup` (upright) undoes the slanted shape so you can use `\textup{\textsf{and}}`